# Cargar datos en un combobox en respuesta a la seleccion de otro comobobox WPF C# SQLServer

Tags: c#, sql-server, wpf

actualmente estoy trabajando en un proyecto de WPF con conexión a base de datos SQLServer, en concreto, mi problema es el siguiente: Tengo 2 Combobox uno es Tipo de evento (Coffe Break, CockTail, Cenas) y el otro es Modalidad de Servicio(Light Break, Journal Break, Day Break, Ejecutiva, Celebración, Quick Cocktail, Ambient Cocktail), estos datos los estoy trayendo desde dos tablas en SQL Server

Aquí es donde tengo que hacer el filtrado, necesito que al seleccionar en el primer Combobox la opción CoffeBreak, solo se muestren las modalidades de servicio Break en el segundo combobox, para Cocktail solo se muestren las modalidades Cocktail y para Cenas solo se muestren Ejecutiva y Celebración respectivamente.

He intentado hacer lo siguiente:

```
private void CbxIdTipoEventoContrato_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {

        Brick.OnBreakEntities bbdd = new Brick.OnBreakEntities();


        if (cbxIdTipoEventoContrato.SelectedValue.Equals(10))
        {
            var llenarCoffe = (from mod in bbdd.ModalidadServicio
                               where mod.IdTipoEvento == 10
                               select new { idt = mod.IdTipoEvento, nomb = mod.Nombre }).ToList();

            cbxIdModalidadContrato.ItemsSource = llenarCoffe;
            cbxIdModalidadContrato.SelectedValuePath = "idt";
            cbxIdModalidadContrato.DisplayMemberPath = "nomb";


        }
        if (cbxIdTipoEventoContrato.SelectedIndex.Equals(20))
        {
            var llenarCocktail = (from mod in bbdd.ModalidadServicio
                                  where mod.IdTipoEvento == 20
                                  select new { idt = mod.IdTipoEvento, nomb = mod.Nombre }).ToList();

            cbxIdModalidadContrato.ItemsSource = llenarCocktail;
            cbxIdModalidadContrato.SelectedValuePath = "idt";
            cbxIdModalidadContrato.DisplayMemberPath = "nomb";


        }
        if (cbxIdTipoEventoContrato.SelectedIndex.Equals(30))
        {
            var llenarCenas = (from mod in bbdd.ModalidadServicio
                               where mod.IdTipoEvento == 30
                               select new { idt = mod.IdTipoEvento, nomb = mod.Nombre }).ToList();

            cbxIdModalidadContrato.ItemsSource = llenarCenas;
            cbxIdModalidadContrato.SelectedValuePath = "idt";
            cbxIdModalidadContrato.DisplayMemberPath = "nomb";


        }


    }
```

y los combobox los cargo de esta manera

```
private void CbxIdTipoEventoContrato_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Brick.OnBreakEntities bbdd = new Brick.OnBreakEntities();
        var llenarTipoEvento = (from tipoEvento in bbdd.TipoEvento
                                select new
                                { id = tipoEvento.IdTipoEvento,
                                  desc = tipoEvento.Descripcion
                                }).ToList();

        cbxIdTipoEventoContrato.ItemsSource = llenarTipoEvento;
        cbxIdTipoEventoContrato.SelectedValuePath = "id";
        cbxIdTipoEventoContrato.DisplayMemberPath = "desc";


    }
```

el combobox modalidad servicio no lo cargo al inicio por que intento que se carguen al cambiar la selección e los combobox, pero aún así no resulta

Comment: No estoy muy seguro ya que yo siempre uso XAML binding y MVVM, pero es posible que necesites implementar [INotifyPropertyChanged](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: pero como validar la selección del primer combobox, para que al cumplir ciertos requisitos el segundo combobox se modifique?  (ambos datos de los combobox están en tablas de una base de datos)